# Get Chart js object in another function

Tags: jquery, chart.js

After creating a chart like this (with [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/), latest version):

```
var ctx = $('#graph');
var graph = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: someData, 
});
```

I would like to retrieve the Chart object in another function in order to add some data point to it:

```
var graph = ???
graph.data.labels.push(1)
graph.data.datasets[0].data.push(10);
```

How do I get the Chart object?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could directly use the `graph` object without assigning it to another variable *( considering `graph` is a global variable )* to add any sort of data from another function.

Here is a quick example of that ...

```js
var ctx = $('#graph');
var graph = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May"],
        datasets: [{
            label: "Sales",
            data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            fill: false,
            borderColor: '#07C',
        }]
    }
});

function addData() {
    graph.data.labels.push('June')
    graph.data.datasets[0].data.push(6);
    graph.update();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="addData()">Add Data</button>
<canvas id="graph"></canvas>
```

in case: the `graph` variable is inside a function then, you'd have to make the variable *global* to use it from another function

Comment: The code where I create the graph is in a `document.ready` function, so it is not global. I thought it was bad practice to define a variable in global scope, but I was able to solve it this way. Thank you!

Comment: How can we access the chart object if in case we don't save it in a variable or we don't have access to that variable as it might be overridden by some other chart object.

Answer (score 11):

You can just do this:

```
var graph = Chart.getChart('graph')
```

Works in v3 - not sure when it was introduced.

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps:

```
 var ctx = $('#graph');
 var graph = new Chart(ctx, {
     type: 'line',
     data: someData, 
 });
 ctx.data('graph', graph);
```

and later:

```
 var graph = $('#graph').data('graph');
 graph.data.labels.push(1)
 graph.data.datasets[0].data.push(10);
 graph.update();
```

// //

Comment: I like this idea, but far as I can see, modifying that data object has no effect on the rendered chart. For instance, I can read .config.type form it, but changing it does nothing. I wish chart.js would provide some supported way to access the chart object from its DOM element. Seems basic.

Comment: "modifying that data object has no effect on the rendered chart" .. I do believe it does ! you might need to update the chart after modifications

Comment: "I wish chart.js would provide some supported way to access the chart object from its DOM element" ... true ! but this is exactly what I was doing in the above snippet: attaching the chart object as a property to the DOM element, for retrieving it later to work with it

Comment: Doh! You're right, works fine with update(), thanks.

Comment: If I use this, it just tells me that "graph" is undefined when I try to push to it (Cannot read 'data' of undefined).

Comment: Did you forget <canvas id="graph"></canvas> in your template ?

Comment: @Axelle it works for me. You need to do the ctx.data('graph', graph) first, and then do the graph.update(). it totally works.

Comment: @ychen-student like Mario mentioned above, I had a typo in my canvas id which resulted in it not being found.

Answer (score 2):

```
//get object
const chartJS: Chart = $("#myChart").data('chart');

//change something
chartJS.config.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.min = minVal <= 0 ? minVal : minVal - 

//update
chartJS.update();
```

Comment: For me, `$(<appropriateQuerySelector>).data('chart')` returns `undefined`.